# How to do Pagination in android

Tags: android

How to show huge data using pagination,I tried with scroll view but i think it is not correct way to show that much of data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1. Endless ScrollView Class**

```
public abstract class EndlessScrollListener implements AbsListView.OnScrollListener {
    // The minimum amount of items to have below your current scroll position
    // before loading more.
    private int visibleThreshold =4;
    // The current offset index of data you have loaded
    private int currentPage = 0;
    // The total number of items in the dataset after the last load
    private int previousTotalItemCount = 0;
    // True if we are still waiting for the last set of data to load.
    private boolean loading = true;
    // Sets the starting page index
    private int startingPageIndex = 0;

    public EndlessScrollListener() {
    }

    public EndlessScrollListener(int visibleThreshold) {
        this.visibleThreshold = visibleThreshold;
    }

    public EndlessScrollListener(int visibleThreshold, int startPage) {
        this.visibleThreshold = visibleThreshold;
        this.startingPageIndex = startPage;
        this.currentPage = startPage;
    }

    // This happens many times a second during a scroll, so be wary of the code you place here.
    // We are given a few useful parameters to help us work out if we need to load some more data,
    // but first we check if we are waiting for the previous load to finish.
    @Override
    public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount)
    {
        // If the total item count is zero and the previous isn't, assume the
        // list is invalidated and should be reset back to initial state
//        System.out.println("totalItemCount test" +totalItemCount);
//        System.out.println("previousTotalItemCount test" +previousTotalItemCount);
//        System.out.println("loading test" +loading);
//        System.out.println("currentPage test" +currentPage);
        if (totalItemCount < previousTotalItemCount) {
            this.currentPage = this.startingPageIndex;
            this.previousTotalItemCount = totalItemCount;
            if (totalItemCount == 0) { this.loading = true; }
        }
        // If it's still loading, we check to see if the dataset count has
        // changed, if so we conclude it has finished loading and update the current page
        // number and total item count.
        if (loading && (totalItemCount > previousTotalItemCount)) {
            loading = false;
            previousTotalItemCount = totalItemCount;
            currentPage++;
        }

        // If it isn't currently loading, we check to see if we have breached
        // the visibleThreshold and need to reload more data.
        // If we do need to reload some more data, we execute onLoadMore to fetch the data.
        if (!loading && (totalItemCount - visibleItemCount) <= (firstVisibleItem + visibleThreshold)) {
            loading = onLoadMore(currentPage, totalItemCount);
        }
    }

    // Defines the process for actually loading more data based on page
    // Returns true if more data is being loaded; returns false if there is no more data to load.
    public abstract boolean onLoadMore(int page, int totalItemsCount);

    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
        // Don't take any action on changed
    }
}
```

**2. Adapter Class**

```
public class OpenJobAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        private Context context;
        LayoutInflater inflater;
        protected int serverListSize = -1;
        public static final int VIEW_TYPE_LOADING = 0;
        public static final int VIEW_TYPE_ACTIVITY = 1;

        public OpenJobAdapter(Context context) {
            this.context = context;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mOpenJobList.size() + 1;
        }

        @Override
        public int getViewTypeCount() {
            return 2;
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemViewType(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            System.out.println("position :" + position);
            System.out.println("mSpottedDishList.size() :" + mOpenJobList.size());
            return (position >= mOpenJobList.size()) ? VIEW_TYPE_LOADING
                    : VIEW_TYPE_ACTIVITY;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return (getItemViewType(position) == VIEW_TYPE_ACTIVITY) ? mOpenJobList
                    .get(position) : null;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            if (getItemViewType(position) == VIEW_TYPE_LOADING) {
                return getFooterView(position, convertView, parent);
            }
            View dataRow = convertView;
            dataRow = getDataRow(position, convertView, parent);

            return dataRow;
        }

        public View getFooterView(int position, View convertView,
                                  ViewGroup parent) {
            System.out.println("loading view :" + mLoadingFinished);
            if (position >= serverListSize && mLoadingFinished) {
                View view = new View(context);
                return view;
            }

            View row = convertView;
            if (row == null) {
                inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_footer, null);
            }

            return row;
        }

        public View getDataRow(final int position, View convertView,
                            ViewGroup parent) {
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            final viewHold viewholder;
            if (convertView == null) {
                viewholder = new viewHold();
                inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.openjobs_items, null);
                viewholder.mCustomerName = (TextView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.customername);
                viewholder.mDateAndTime = (TextView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.dateandtime);
                viewholder.mCategoryName = (TextView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.categoryname);
                viewholder.mIssue = (TextView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.issue);
                viewholder.mRatings = (TextView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.ratings);
                convertView.setTag(viewholder);
            } else {
                viewholder = (viewHold) convertView.getTag();
            }
            try {
                viewholder.mCustomerName.setText(mOpenJobList.get(position).get(
                        "serviceCategory"));

            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return convertView;
        }

        class viewHold {
            public TextView mCustomerName, mDateAndTime, mCategoryName, mIssue, mRatings;
        }
    }
```

**3. Listview scroll listener**

```
 mListOpenJob.setOnScrollListener(new EndlessScrollListener(0, 0) {
                @Override
                public boolean onLoadMore(int page, int totalItemsCount) {
                    if (Utils.isOnline(OpenJobsActivity.this)) {
//Calling api
                        new OpenJobData().execute(page);
                    } else {
                        Utils.displayToast(OpenJobsActivity.this, getString(R.string.nonet));
                    }
                    return true;
                }
            });
```

**4.Calling Api and make sure that all page is finished or not using boolean flag**

```
private boolean getopenjoblist(int skip) {
        String url;
        url = "Your url";
        try {
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(HttpUtil.apiGETResponseWithHeaders(url, getApplicationContext()));
            if (json.getString("http_code").equals("400")) {
                mLoadingFinished = true;
            }

            //do whatever here
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: i declared activity in androidmanifest.xml and also clean and build and restarted eclipse.